# On 32-bit arm, can I get the upper bits of a double precision bit pattern into an integer register?

Tags: assembly, arm

On 32-bit ARM, `vmov.f32    r0, s0` will copy the single-precision (float32) register `s0` into `r0` as a bit pattern.

Is there a way to similarly get the upper bits of a float64 (those that control signedness, NaN and infinities)?

Comment: It would be `vmov r0, d0[1]` to move the high word from `d0` to `r0`. You can also do `vmov r0, r1, d0` to split `d0` into `r0` (low word) and `r1` (high word) in a single operation.

Comment: @jasonharper: That's what I thought too from reading the architecture manual, but I can't get either instruction to assemble in GAS.  I've tried a variety of `.arch` and `.cpu` combinations.  Does it work for you?

Comment: Which instruction set extensions are you permitted to use?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `vmov Rt, Dn[x]` instruction:

```
        .syntax unified
        .arch armv7-a
        .arch_extension simd

        vmov r0, d0[1]
```

This moves the 32 bit sub word at index 1 (i.e. the high 32 bit) of `d0` into `r0`.  An alternative option is to make use of the fact that each double precision register is overlaid by two single precision registers.  So the same effect is achieved by issuing

```
        vmov r0, s1
```

However, this only works for those double precision registers for which corresponding single precision registers exist (i.e. `d0` to `d15`).